# How do I close all tabs in SQLWorkbenchJ?

Tags: sql-workbench-j

Quite often I would open a bunch of tabs in SQLWorkbenchJ to run some ad-hoc SQL queries, and I wouldn't need them anymore afterwards. I could close them one at a time, but is there a way to close all the tabs at once (since I might have like 20+)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right click on one of the tabs and choose "Close others". That will close all editor tabs, except that one.